# Очередность приложений

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Можно ли в c# поменять очередность окон приложения, к примеру в приложении произошло событие и его окно по отношению к другим приложениям, становиться основным в Win.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, поменять порядок _окон_?

Comment: При срабатывании события перенесите фокус на нужное окно

Comment: нене в самом Wndows между приложениями

Comment: А можно "развернуть" идею, которую вы хотите реализовать? и на каком UI: WinForms или WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для c++ было бы так:
Для начала надо получить идентификатор окна:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Untitled - Notepad");
```

Затем передать этот идентификатор в функцию:

```
SetActiveWindow(hWnd);
```

Comment: Вы языком не ошиблись?

Comment: А должен был ошибиться? Вы не знакомы с WinAPI ?

Comment: Отчего же, знаком. А вы знакомы с C#?

Comment: Предпологал, что ознакомлен) Вижу, вы поопытнее меня на SO, обьясните, что не так?

Comment: Ну, в C# нельзя использовать `#include`, и он не совместим с C++ по исходникам. Поэтому там нет типа `HWND` (и его нельзя подключить). И функции из WinAPI подключаются [через interop](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html).

Comment: Хм... про тип не знал, спасибо